# Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, vlookup

I am trying to send a query to Access to fill in a certain value of my worksheet. I would get this worksheet by getting the current user's login name and look through a column. This column gets updated according to a column in access. The value I would need is in the column to the RIGHT of the column I search through. I have the below code as a temporary try-out to get my VLookup to work

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim user, cUser As String
    user = (Environ$("Username"))
    cUser = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(user, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C1000"), -2, False)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Value = cUser
    End Sub
```

I am trying to get the value that I need into cell F1. If this works, I would put the value into a variable and add this to my query. I'll also insert error handling to ensure the code keeps working, but for now I just want it to work on my 1 value that I know is in the column.

Comment: You can't reference a column outside the lookup area or before the index column. You need to use INDEX/MATCH or `Find()` for what you want here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim user As String, cUser As String '// Note you have to declare the type each time!
    user = Environ$("USERNAME")
    cUser = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C").Find(user).Offset(, -2).Value
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Value = cUser
End Sub
```

Which can be simplified again to:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C").Find(Environ$("USERNAME")).Offset(, -2).Value
End Sub
```

A vlookup simply isn't suitable for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found a guide doing almost the same thing so I though I could just follow this. Your answer works!

Comment: No problem - the reason for your initial problem was because you're trying to refrence a column that isn't being looked at as part of your vlookup - but rather than go through the pain of explaining why you would need to use INDEX/MATCH instead and converting that to a VBA version I thought it would be easier to use `.Find()` instead. I would still advise having a look at how INDEX/MATCH works though for future reference.